# Can't show button in relation to the zoomScale of scrollView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I want to show my button when the user have zoomed enough in. I want to use the scrollViews zoomscale to determine this.

I do this

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (self.scrollView.zoomScale == 2.0)
    {
         [button setHidden:NO];
    }
    return imageView;
}
```

But I get bad access when I run my app o.O

Thanks

Comment: which line throws the bad access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mostlikely want to call this method instead:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(float)scale
```

Or even better use:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    NSLog(@"%f", scrollView.zoomScale);
}
```

Put your if-statement in any of the methods but don't use '==' it's rarely precisely 2.0
Use '<' instead.

Comment: Thanks alot for the help. It works now ^^ Hmm... I'm wondering... Why doesn't it work in my way? Shouldn't it be the same? :S